# Cons of ASP.NET memberships roles and authentication?

Tags: asp.net

Fairly new to ASP.NET's membership roles and forms authentication, it would seem that this would save more time and effort for my implementation.

But, I would also like to know if it comes in all goodness or does it carry any extra baggage (cons) in terms of:

1. Performance
2. Scalability

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Which provider do you plan to use? ADAM, Active Directory, Sql, Ms-Access, XML? Performance and scalability will be determined by that more than anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never had a problem with performance or scalability with the default providers. Here are two tips that I've picked up along the way.

1. If you are using the providers and hashing passwords in a load-balanced setup. You will have to specify your machine key in the web.config
2. By default, users roles are not cached so every time you need to check a user role, you will make a round-trip to the DB. Using the cacheRolesInCookie="true" attribute in the  tag in the web.config will cache them for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the SQL Membership providers in ASP.Net in many large scale web applications and have never had any issue with it.

In our current application we've had to add extra fields and we expose these using an extra API.

[Optimize ASP.NET Membership Stored Procedures for greater speed and scalability](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2009/03/13/optimize-asp-net-membership-stored-procedures-for-greater-speed-and-scalability.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no real baggage in terms of performance and scalability. If anything, the real baggage is in terms of testability and portability (gobal static singletons are bad), but you can code around that.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work just fine, you can always switch provider or write your own later on.

I've written a provider that works as a layer between the ASP.NET authentication system and POCO classes together with a repository and nHibernate, that way I can let users login and get authenticated the ASP.NET MVC out-of-the-box-way, yet have the users and roles as any other model/view/controller in my system. Also by using IoC and interfaces I can use the exact same provider in different projects that handle users in different ways. Yay. Strange though that something like that didn't come out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default providers then it can be quite difficult to do things like search or filter users or do admin-type things, since you can't (easily) query the database directly. You have to go through the API, and it's quite limited. So, if you want to produce a lot of reports on users, be aware this is not easy to to efficiently.